# Ошибка JavaFX MediaPlayer. MediaException: Could not create player!

Tags: файлы, javafx, исключения, видео, mediaplayer

MediaPlayer никак не хочет воспроизводить видео. Бросает исключение: MediaException: Could not create player! при создании.

```
Group root = new Group();

final String PATH = "file:///home/semyon/Projects/mediaPlayer/hpend.mp4";

MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(PATH));
MediaView view = new MediaView(player);

root.getChildren().add(view);
stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
stage.show();

player.play();
```

Облазил пол гугла. В том числе и стековерфлоу. Чаще всего рекомендуют делать вот так:

```
Media media = new Media(new File(PATH).toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

Но это, к сожалению, не помогает. Видел на одном форуме что проблема в файловом протоколе(и это кому-то помогло), но как решить никто словом не обмолвился.

ps: Если не отлавливать исключение то выдвет следующее:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in           Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN :  com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
at sample.Main.start(Main.java:32)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
... 11 more
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Скажите а когда Вы тестировали рекомендуемый способ из переменной PATH вы схему убирали? т.е  MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(new File("/home/semyon/Projects/mediaPlayer/hpend.mp4").toURI().toString())));

Comment: Судя по src инициализация плеера действительно в некоторых случаях выбрасывая исключение с маркером "Could not create player!" лишь задав не корректно путь относительно схемы.

Comment: Пытался я по-разному. В моем, в вашем и в таком: "new File("hpend.mp4").toURI().toString()" случае бросает одинаковое исключение. Тут вероятно не в пути дело

Comment: Кстати, пробовал я подгружать [видео](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv) с интернета
, как часто рекомендуют. Программа запускается но видео не работает.

Comment: Хммм в том то и дело что я Ваш код запустил из под Win со своими коррективами  и отработал он без исключений.Просмотрев src наткнулся на ситуацию с кривой схемой(невозможно создать плеер) в иных случаях  некорректный путь выбрасывает.Вечером если вопрос не разрешится проверю под Ubuntu...есть [версия](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090356/javafx-mediaplayer-could-not-create-player-error-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: По сути эксперемент не удался Ubuntu 16.04 - плеер не создается что самое интересное 16 версии как поддерживаемой нет и [тут](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html)...Хотя все с аудио проблем нет в экземпляр класса укладывается мп3 и отрабатывает далее касательно линии декодеров (Фабрика вызываемая в методе вытягивает плеер де факто из системы) кое-что доствил но видимого эфекта нет...Пока так : /

Comment: В общем трабы из-за моей Kubuntu 16.04 LTS. Теперь пытаться запускать на более ранних версиях ?

Еще на сайте Oracle сказано что требуется  GLIB 2.28. Я разумеется пытался его установить, но это никак не повлияло.

Comment: Можете задать вопрос на stackoverflow.com - вдруг кто пережил без миграции.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
public class SomeClass extends Application{


    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {       
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);

        Media pick = new Media("file:/home/semyon/Projects/mediaPlayer/hpend.mp4");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(pick);
        player.play();

        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);
        ((Group)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Media Player");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Ничего нового :(

Comment: Поменяйте путь. Уберите //. с ними у меня тоже бросает это же исключение.

Comment: Пробовал я. Исключение вылазит в обоих вариантах. И в нескольких других

Comment: Прошу прощения, попробуйте целиком мой код, просто для пробы. Если не работают ВСЕ варианты, то вероятно дело и не в коде.

Comment: Запускал ваш код как только вы мне ответили. Еще раз попробовал - не работает. Пытался через FileChooser задать путь, но все тоже самое. Где-то видел что у меня каких-то либ нет. Что-то типа libavformat, libglib2.0-dev. Как считаете может быть что-то подобное ? Вероятно стоит поставить виртуалку и  на винде протестировать

Comment: Еще никак не хотят воспроизводиться видео, подгружаемые из интернета. Но все прекрасно запускается

Comment: Да, вероятно надо пробовать с библиотеками. У вас запускается и ничего нет или только видео не работает а звук есть?

Comment: И звука и видео нет.

Comment: как не жаль но - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153227/adding-other-video-codecs-dvd-support-to-javafx-2-2 Работаю не самые современные кодеки. Еще возможен вариант с конвертацией налету, во время исполнения программы.